# Best way to create and run typescript files in a electron project with sveltekit

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron, sveltekit

I recently started a project with this template (https://github.com/FractalHQ/sveltekit-electron).
However i noticed that in the `src` directory all typescript files seem to be treated as 'pages', indicated by a vite log `[svelte] 11:45:18 PM [vite] page reload src/main.ts`, hence its not running, as well as it would seem they get compiled to, well, im not very sure.., i would guess somewhere in the `.sveltekit` folder, however i cannot seem to find the compiled contents anywhere.

I would very much like to run typescript files, as well as rewrite the electron.cjs file to a typescript file.

I already did try some approaches, i tried very simply with tsc running `tsc ./src/main.ts`, and while it did sortof work, i would like it to be in some sort of directory, e.g `compiled` and also it had added the line `['default']` in font of all dependency imports, which I had to manually remove. All and all this is sortof doable, however a more hands off approach would be preferable, if possible.

How could I go about going around this problem ?